# Doctrine tries to access a column previously dropped in a migration

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, migration, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have changed the schema of a Symfony application by transforming a one-to-many relationship to a many-to-many relationship between a `Sample` model and a `Collector` model. The `Sample` model had a `collector_id` foreign key and now there is an intermediate model (`SampleCollectors`) with two foreign keys: `sample_id` and `collector_id`.

```
Sample:
  columns:
    id:  { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    ...
    collector_id:  ... # This column is removed
    ...
  relations:
    ...
    Collectors:  { foreignAlias: Collectors, class: Collector, local: sample_id, foreign: collector_id, refClass: SampleCollectors }

Collector:
  columns:
    id:       { type: integer, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    ...
  relations:
    Samples:  { foreignAlias: Samples, class: Sample, local: collector_id, foreign: sample_id, refClass: SampleCollectors }


SampleCollectors:
  columns:
    sample_id:    { type: integer, primary: true }
    collector_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Sample:       { onDelete: cascade }
```

I have edited the `schema.yml file` like above and executed the following tasks:

1. `php symfony doc:generate-migrations-diff`
2. `php symfony doc:build --all-classes`

which has rebuilt every involved model/form/filter and created two migration classes.

Since the database is already in production-mode, I have tuned the migration classes to move the foreign key of the one-to-many relationship (`Sample`.`collector_id`) to the many-to-many intermediate table (`SampleCollectors`.`collector_id`):

```php
public function preUp() {
  $sampleTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Sample');
  // I do this because collector_id has disappeared after model regeneration.
  $sampleTable->setColumn('collector_id', 'integer', null, array('type' => 'integer'));
  $this->samples = $sampleTable->findAll()->toArray();
}

public function up() {
  // ...
  $this->removeColumn('sample', 'collector_id');

  // ...
  $this->createTable('sample_collectors', array(...), array(
    'type' => 'INNODB',
    'primary' => array(0 => 'sample_id', 1 => 'collector_id'),
     ...));
}

public function postUp() {
  foreach ( $this->samples as $sample ) {
    $sampleCollector = new SampleCollectors();
    $sampleCollector->setSampleId($sample['id']);
    $sampleCollector->setCollectorId($sample['collector_id']);
    $sampleCollector->trySave();
  }
}
```

I have migrated the database and everything went apparently well.

But now that I'm updating the controllers, views, etc., Doctrine still tries to retrieve the `collector_id` column from Sample, instead of navigating through the many-to-many relationship.

Since the `Sample` model does not store a reference to it anymore, why does Doctrine insist on that? I checked the `BaseSample` class and it does not have a `hasColumn()` method setting a column `collector_id`. BTW, I clear the cache as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using apc (or any other backend) to cache the dql?

Comment: Yes, I'm using APC. Could it be related?

Comment: Not unless your doctrine is configured to use it. Try to restart your web server and you'll see.

Comment: @greg0ire It was the APC cache actually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had configured Doctrine to use the APC cache system in `ProjectConfiguration` class:

```
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager) {
  $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, new Doctrine_Cache_Apc());
}
```

This cache is not cleared when you execute `php symfony cache:clear`, since is not a Symfony thing but a PHP and web server thing.

You can either restart the web server or use `apc_clear_cache()`, as noted in this [question regarding APC cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911158/592454).