# Magento - issue working with forms

Tags: php, magento, authentication, apache2, magento-1.6

I've set up a new server for my magentocommerce.

Unfortunatly when I moved the domain to the new location (tests have been done using another domain) a weird issue started happening: when the login page displays on the frontend, or the backend and I (and customers, of course) do submit the right credentials the page refresh, the cookie gets set but the form is displayed again. It's such a cache being served instead of the right content (catalog).

The only solution actually is delete the cache on the browser and retry.

I've used varnish http accelerator for two days, but since I've had too much issues dealing with it I uninstalled it and cleaned things up (now there's only the apache instance to serve user requests).

I also installed APC caching and Fooman Speedster.

**What can it be to cause this issue?**

Can you please help me to get in the right direction to fix this issue? On the old server it was not happening, but since that time there have been some modification to the store (nothing to do with authentication anyway).

The apache error log does not report anything, the only thing in there is `PHP:  syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/apc.ini on line 4` which has to do with the line `apc.enabled = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the System -> Configuration -> Web tab in the admin panel and see if the Cookie Path and Cookie Domain are set correctly for the new server. You can do it directly in the database as well. In this case, search for rows with `web/cookie/cookie_path` and `web/cookie/cookie_domain` paths. Setting them to empty values in the admin panel or NULL in the database may also help.

You should also clear Magento cache (System -> Cache Management) and APC cache (here's how to do it: [How to clear APC cache entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solves your specific form problem but we had the same error in the apache error log.

Our failure was, we've copied the apc.ini code from http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/speeding-up-magento-with-apc-or-memcached/. They use "#" for comments.

Turns out we had to use ";" for comments. After these changes, there were no more errors in the apache error log.