# Is APC opcode cache shared between PHP-FPM pools/workers?

Tags: apc, php, opcode-cache

Internet has a lot of discussions that calling `apc_cache_clear()` in CLI does not clear opcode caches from "web" PHP processes, whether they are run inside Apache or by FPM (see [How to clear APC cache entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries) ). As a suggested solution, it's possible to create a simple PHP page that calls `apc_cache_clear()`, and call that from CLI. [Symfony's ApcBundle](https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle) does that.

If the `apc_cache_clear()` from CLI does not empty the cache from Apache/FPM, does it between FPM workers? If I call /clear_apc_cache.php over HTTP, it's run by only by one of the FPM worker processes. So, is the APC opcode cache **really** shared between pools and workers - and more specific: is it cleared from all workers automatically?

Comment: As far as I understand FPM and APC, I believe they are shared.  You basically have one instance of PHP running.  Therefore, only one instance of APC.

Comment: Thanks @tubaguy50035 for a comment. I think I need to do some more research to be sure...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All the php-fpm workers share the same opcode cache as the parent php-fpm process; [source](http://news.php.net/php.internals/63539). If you have a /apc_clear_cache.php file and you call that over HTTP (using something like curl), you will clear the opcode cache for all workers using the same php-fpm master process.

This [blog article](http://blog.wepay.com/weploy-wepays-deployment-tool/) has a very good explanation of how apc works and how to clear it effectively during release.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question with good sources. This clarified my issue. =)

Comment: As written [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12981832/1447317) you should clear APC cache in context of HTTP request, however, it will clear cache for **all** pools, which are forked from same master process (this is typical for most distros).

Comment: I think the child processes are forked from the same master process even they're in different pools, so there's only one shared apc cache. One way to work around is to start different php-fpm master processes.

Comment: @Jerry You are right! The realpath cache is local to the workers, not the apc cache. I will update my answer.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII Your answer still states "It is not shared between pools;" which is incorrect, as the above comments have stated, if the pools are from the same master PHP-FPM process the pools will share the opcode cache. Additionally, cache clearing is not limited to just that pool, it will clear the cache for all pools which come from the same parent PHP-FPM process.

Comment: @Herman I believe you misread [source](http://news.php.net/php.internals/63539). It states that pools forked from the same parent process are able to share the opcode cache, this is exactly what happens. What the poster in the link was talking about was the possibility of sharing the opcode cache with pools forked from _different_ parent processes. I have had the issue with the opcode being shared between pools, and the common answer is to start multiple PHP-FPM master processes. [Example, and partial explanation](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,122844) apc.php's file listing reveals it.

Comment: This answer should state clearly that if the opcode cache is not shared between pools the statcache is shared between pools in processes and that this means pools using apc, for example, may have some file name conflicts.

Comment: @Phizes thank you for catching this. I updated the answer to make it clear that different php-fpm pools share an opcode cache.

Comment: @regilero are you referring to the statcache for realpath? I think that is out of the scope of this question. The link I provided in my answer does speak to the statcache differnces though.

Comment: @Herman J. Radtke III, yes, looking at misunderstanding in comments I think adding a clear note about that in the answer would made it a better one. Links provided are really good but explaining here that the opcode cache is not 'all' the apc cache and may explain shared-things-bugs would be nice.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII - just wanted to inform you that the blog article is no longer available.

Comment: @ConAntonakos it looks like they changed the blog around. I fixed the link. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can clear the opcode cache via the cli without having to deploy the files to your website if you execute the script via the FastCGI interface directly.

I've created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stuartcarnie/5523506) which you can use on your servers to clear the php5-fpm cache.

If you're using unix sockets:

`php clear-apc.php --sock /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Otherwise:

`php clear-apc.php --port=[port]`

or omit for default `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful gist in general and could be easily used also for cache warming and other similar operations in the application server without.

Comment: Great idea – may even incorporate that ability :)

Comment: Gist doesn't exist anymore :-(

Comment: @StuartCarnie what about if I get this error while execute the script `Primary script unknown`?

Answer (score 3):

I have just found out that different pools also share the same APC cache, at least in PHP 5.4 with FPM and as far as the opcode cache content is concerned.

This is how I noticed it:

I have set up multiple PHP-FPM pools, where each pool is chrooted under /srv/www/domain.com/ directory.

The main location for PHP scripts is /srv/www/domain.com/docroot/.

Now, if I create a file /srv/www/domain_1.com/docroot/test.php, and load the script, it shows what it should show.

However, when I create the file /srv/www/domain_2.com/docroot/test.php, the contents show also up under domain_1.com.

I think this happens because APC uses the file location as the key for its cache, and in both cases the key is /docroot/test.php.

Clearing the opcode cache might be restricted only to a single pool. I haven't tested this though.

*EDIT* Clearing the opcode cache isn't restircted to a single app pool, the complete APC cache is cleared when apc_cache_clear() is called.

I also tried to use apc.mmap_file_mask to specify a different mask for every pool. This didn't change anything, updates in one app pool files were seen in other pools.

This behaviour was observed with apc.stat=0 setting. All changes to files are monitored with lsyncd, forcing a recompile of the entry in APC cache.

- Tero

Comment: Kiitos Tero - as far as I've understood the [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12981832/769144), it seems that the opcode cache is owned the main process, so this behavior is kind of expected... except that definitely the whole source file path should be the key. I have to test this in my own setup too.