# How to force reload of configuration after modifying LocalSettings.php file in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I need to reload configuration after modifying LocalSettings.php without restarting Apache.

How is it possible?

Kind regards

Comment: How do you run php: as php-fpm or mod_php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `LocalSettings.php` is cached with `opcache`, you need to flush it. How it is done, is told [here](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-clear-php-opcache/). In a nutshell:

- mod_php: `apachectl graceful`,
- php-fpm: `service php-fpm reload`,
- CGI or FastCGI: no need.

If you have APC: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392464/6632736).

Comment: `apachectl graceful` solved the problem, Thank you