# How to flush APC class loader cache?

Tags: symfony, apc

The [Performance Symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html#caching-the-autoloader-with-apc) mentions the need to flush the APC cache when some classes have moved and this is indeed needed.

However, I don't find how to clear the APC cache for autoloaders. I tried with the PHP `apc_clear_cache()` function, but it didn't help.

How to clear this APC cache?

Comment: apc_clear_cache(<string>) must works well. Do you already check if your problem is not with the symfony cache?

Comment: Thanks, I will try with `apc_clear_cache` again, I may have not used the correct string. I cleared the Symfony cache as well (and all Composer generated autoloaders), but with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Mauro apc_clear_cache can also take an argument to clear different types of apc caches:

```
  apc_clear_cache();
  apc_clear_cache('user');
  apc_clear_cache('opcode');
```

Please also see [this related post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries).

And there is also [ApcBundle](https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle) which adds a Symfony apc:clear command.

Comment: For information, the mentioned lines have to be executed in the Symfony2 application. Adding them temporarily in `app.php` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Just create one simple controller ApcController as below

```
<?php

namespace Rm\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

/**
 * apc cache clear controller
 */
class ApcController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * clear action
     *
     * @Route("/cc", name="rm_demo_apc_cache_clear")
     *
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN")
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     */
    public function cacheClearAction(Request $request)
    {

        $message = "";

        if (function_exists('apc_clear_cache') 
                && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '>=') 
                && apc_clear_cache()) {

            $message .= ' User Cache: success';

        } elseif (function_exists('apc_clear_cache') 
                && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<') 
                && apc_clear_cache('user')) {

            $message .= ' User Cache: success';

        } else {

            $success = false;
            $message .= ' User Cache: failure';

        }

        if (function_exists('opcache_reset') && opcache_reset()) {

            $message .= ' Opcode Cache: success';

        } elseif (function_exists('apc_clear_cache') 
                && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<') 
                && apc_clear_cache('opcode')) {

            $message .= ' Opcode Cache: success';

        } else {
            $success = false;
            $message .= ' Opcode Cache: failure';
        }

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()
                            ->add('success', $message);

        // redirect
        $url = $this->container
                ->get('router')
                ->generate('sonata_admin_dashboard');

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

}
```

Then import controller routes to your **routing.yml**

```
#src/Rm/DemoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
apc:
    resource: "@RmDemoBundle/Controller/ApcController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /apc
```

Now you can clear apc cache using below url:

```
http://yourdomain/apc/cc
```

NOTE : @Secure(roles="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN") annotation, this will protect you apc cache url from unauthorized access.