# How to configure APC with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, apc

I can't find any documentation as to how to configure APC with Symfony2. I don't want to write any specific code or have anything advanced, just the basic APC setup with Symfony2.

I've uncommented the two lines in app.php and everything seems ok (the site runs for a start).

However...

(1) I hear people talk about "restarting APC" - what does that mean? Can I not just run this any time I want a full clean:

```
php console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

(2) In app/config_prod.yml, I see this:

```
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: null
    #validation:
    #    cache: apc
```

...what does uncommenting that do?

It seems too easy just to uncomment the two lines in app.php. SUrely there must be more config options. Again I don't want an advanced setup.

I don't even know if APC is running, but considering the site runs that tells me it is (before it didn't and I needed to install APC in PHP).

When I searched "APC" in the Symfony2 cookbook it returned literally nothing.

Comment: Have you seen this page: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apc_clear_cache() will clear the system cache and calling apc_clear_cache('user') will clear the user cache. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/911219/1501189

also, to get apc up and running in symfony, make sure u enable it in your php.ini for CLI aswell! not only in your php.ini that your apache uses, this had me fooled for a while when i was trying to get this running myself

To check if symfony is using APC, click the profiler at the bottom of the page (when in dev environment), then click config on the left, and it will tell your wether or not APC is enabled