# Find dependencies in magento

Tags: magento, module, dependencies

i just deactivate a custom module but magento is still looking for a file from that module and got this error:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: apc failed to locate Mage/Gomage/Navigation/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Category/Column.php - bailing in /vagrant/shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
0 /vagrant/shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include()  [autoload('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
4 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1346): class_exists('Mage_Gomage_Nav...')
5 /vagrant/shop/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('gomage_navigati...', Array)
6 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(383):  Mage::getModel('gomage_navigati...')
7 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
8 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
9 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
10 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
11 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
12 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
13 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
14 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
15 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
16 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
17 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
18 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(261): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
19 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
20 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
21 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
22 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
23 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
24 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
25 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
26 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
27 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
28 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
29 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
 30 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
31 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
32 /vagrant/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
33 /vagrant/shop/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
34 {main}
```

i have been trying to find where is this module called in other place in the code to remove it but i cant find it, so what is the best way to search for this dependencies in magento?

Comment: Take a look at your setup installer for that module, did it add an `Attributes` to your product or category table?

Comment: It looks like there is some attribute created for category that uses GoMage_Navigation model as a source. Check the `eav_attribute` table for category attributes (entity_type_id is taken from `eav_entity_type`). At my default 1.8 installation category attributes are those with entity_type_id = 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stack:

```
#7 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201):    Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#8 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#9 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /vagrant/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
```

you can see that it happens in the category tabs when preparing the category attributes, so probably you need to delete an attribute from your database which uses a source model of the deleted module. Have a look in the eav_attribute table and look in the column source_model. There you will find a reference to gomage_navigation.

Edit: To speed this up, you can also look in the setup scripts of the deleted module which attributes it creates and then pinpoint the warrior of destruction ;)

answered Jun 4 at 16:11
mpaepper

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear cache by following step

> (**Admin** > **System** > **Manage Cache** > Click on **Select all** and **Refresh** and press **Submit** button

2. Delete all files and folders in `/vagrant/shop/var/cache`

Comment: thanks but it did not work :(, any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you have installed external cache library, such as APC? In that case flush APC cache. Use `apc_clear_cache()` function to clear apc cache, more referehce here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries