# Doctrine ReflectionException property does not exist

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to add Doctrine on top of an existing database.  I let Doctrine generate annotated entities and adjusted from there.  When I try to load the entity below I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Property Users\\User::$resellerID does not exist'`

```
class User
{
    /* ... */

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Resellers\Reseller")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="reseller",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resellerID", referencedColumnName="resellerID")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="resellerID", referencedColumnName="resellerID")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $reseller;

    /* ... */
}
```

Both the `user` and `reseller` tables have `resellerID` columns.  My understanding is that for joining ID columns you don't add the ID columns as properties in the entity class.  So what's causing the ReflectionException?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since I had renamed the autogenerated property from `resellerID` to `reseller` (after trying to use it) it turns out I needed to clear the Doctrine cache.

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:result
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:query
php vendor/bin/doctrine.php orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

Or, if you are using Symfony with Doctrine:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Comment: What if none of the given answers works ?
 I 've using Symfony since 2014 and never had such issue until I start to use 'json' and 'json_array' types in an entity .

Comment: @DiegoFavero I would open a new question specific to your scenario.  Link back to this one so you don't get flagged as a duplicate. I've never used those types in an entity so maybe there's something special that needs to be done.

Comment: Paid a bit of research, and I think I will open an issue ticket on Doctrine's page because I did not find any similar problem !

Comment: to run all these commands with the same order in the answer is really important btw.

Answer (score 3):

For me [clearing the PHP APC cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911219/289404) was the solution

```
<?php
apc_clear_cache();
```

Comment: This was what I needed in the end - clearing the doctrine cache turned out to be a temporary measure and it was only when I restarted memcached that I got rid of the error for good.

Comment: Same idea if using opcache with the opcache.validate_timestamps = false flag. Clear the cache by restarting the web server. Thanks @michalzuber for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, it helped me

```
php artisan  doctrine:clear:metadata:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually on production you want something like this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

My error still occurred when I attempted to clear the doctrine cache.

What worked for me was to manually clear the cache by deleting the folder under `/storage/framework/cache/*`

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony, due to Docker container permissions, I had to manually delete everything under /var/cache/.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this while using a Docker container:

1. Use Terminal within your PHP/Symfony container.
2. Enter the doctrine cache clear commands referenced in older answers:

```
    php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
    php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
    php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

2. Do the APC cache clear also referenced in older answers:

```
    php -r "apc_clear_cache();"
```

3. Restart your PHP / Symfony container in Docker.

The restart as a last step ends up clearing whatever is lingering, at least in my case. Hope this helps anyone else using Docker.