# ReflectionException: Property $id does not exist

Tags: php, string, symfony, primary-key

I've changed the primary key of an entity, but now I'm getting back this error:

```
ReflectionException Property DnD\\ApiBundle\\Entity\\Agent::$id does not exist
```

My entity is this:

```
<?php

namespace DnD\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

/**
 * Agent
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DnD\ApiBundle\Repository\AgentRepository")
 */
class Agent
{

  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @Groups({"list", "details"})
   * @Id
   * @Column(type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $agentId;

  ...
```

I've already clear doctrine cache, but the error persists. Why is this happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187097/doctrine-reflectionexception-property-does-not-exist) and tried to clean doctrine cache?

Comment: 1. avoid using private properties except are actually need to restrict child's access to this prop.
2. have you updated the getter method for the model identificator?

Comment: Possibly because you have orm files in MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine so your annotations are not being seen.  Can't mix the two within a bundle.

Comment: hey,May i know how you fixed this?

Comment: Didn't fix it, I ended up using the normal autogenerated id as pk

Comment: ohkay! I am getting a similar error but not for the primary key though.It is showing property does not exist for a field which is not in the entity and which need not be in the entity.Let me know if you have any idea about this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906530/reflectionexception-in-jms

Answer (score 7):

clearing cache by app/console its not enough,
remove cache folder completely, it works for me

Comment: Please expand you answer with why this works.  And a link to the reference if you found it online.

Comment: did you try to clear the right environment you are using? like `app/console cache:clear --env=test`