# How to modify server response 304 not modified http header response in browser

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, joomla3.0, browser-cache

I am using Joomla version 3.2.3
I am using cache both APC and turned on the browser cache in system plugins.

I have modified an article and even change the date modified.

After that I have deleted all the cache in joomla.

But when I am opening the page in in the browser, it is still showing the previous version even after using ctrl+R or F5.

How can I tell the browser that the page is modified, which is showing 304-not modified response header in firebug

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending a query string (or additional parameters) to the page URL:

example.com/test.php**?refresh=123**

example.com/test.php?page=main**&refresh=123**

But it's also likely the page is cached on the server still somewhere. Try clearing Joomla cache again and also [clear APC cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries)