# How to unset $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] in PHP 7.3

Tags: php, nginx, http-authentication, fpm

I installed APC status page [script](https://electrictoolbox.com/apc-php-cache-information/) on my server to see APC status. This lets you set a username and password via HTTP Authentication to view more detailed information.

Once logged in via HTTP Authentication, php info has set $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] and now all HTTP requests on the server are failing because it asks for authentication.

How can I unset or disable this in PHP? I have no intention of using that script again and it's affecting operations of other files on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Restarting PHP FPM and Nginx.
Clearing Application Caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use apc_clear_cache() function.
Please refer to related question on SO.
[How to clear APC cache entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911158/how-to-clear-apc-cache-entries)